# ReactJS Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: reactjs, jsx

This is the error I am facing:

```
djacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?
```

I am trying to implement only the admin can see menu 2 and menu 3 so write the code this way:

```
          <a>menu 1</a>
          {(this.props.person.ADMIN) ?
            <a>Menu 2</a>
            <a>Menu 3</a>
            :

            ''
          }
```

When I write this way removing another anchor tag:

```
  <a>menu 1</a>
  {(this.props.person.ADMIN) ?
    <a>Menu 2</a>
    :

    ''
  }
```

It works. What's wrong with this if I use two item in the condition? How can I use more than one item inside this block?

Comment: The error message tells you both: 1. exactly what's wrong (adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag); and 2. how to fix it (did you want a JSX fragment). Please *read the error messages*, they're there for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fragment to wrap the two component. You are returning two elements simultaneously which causes that error.

```
<a>menu 1</a>
 {(this.props.person.ADMIN) 

   ? <>
       <a>Menu 2</a>
       <a>Menu 3</a>
     </>

   :

     ''
  }
```

You can also return an array instead of wrapping the component in one tag.

```
<a>menu 1</a>
 {(this.props.person.ADMIN) 

   ? [
       <a>Menu 2</a>
       <a>Menu 3</a>
     ]

   :

     ''
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. The solution is just using a `React.Fragment` like so:

```
<a>menu 1</a>
  {(this.props.person.ADMIN) ?
    <>
        <a>Menu 2</a>
        <a>Menu 3 </>
    </>
     :
    ''
  }
```

Comment: @howrecepes which answer comes first, if you sort them by oldest?

Comment: alex answer come first

Comment: Yeah, that's fair :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this eror message and I found [this issue](https://www.giters.com/mdx-js/mdx/issues/767) mentioning compiler issues with empty lines, and yeah... it was an empty line separating my jsx component into two, so I just had to remove the empty line and add a big TROUBLESHOOTING.md file in the repo so everyone knows this and don't spend a day figuring out, like me.